# MySQL/Java set<type> and get<type> What types perform better?

Tags: java, mysql, performance, jdbc

Given this java code...

```
PreparedStatement s = prepare("SELECT ...")
ResultSet r = s.executeQuery()
r.next()
s = prepare("UPDATE ...")
s.setInt(1, r.getInt(3))
s.setInt(2, r.getInt(1))
s.executeUpdate()
s = prepare("UPDATE ...")
s.setInt(1, r.getInt(3))
s.setInt(2, r.getInt(2))
s.executeUpdate()
```

It seems to me that MySQL JDBC would have to do `...intValue()` and `new Integer(..)`. Does anybody know if the above code would perform better if I used `setObject`/`getObject` instead. What about any other types?

I expect to be using JDBC for years to come so I thought I might as well stop guessing.

Answer (score 0):

The signatures on getInt() and setInt() are native ints, not Object or Integer.  Frankly, the overhead of creating an object compared to doing a query would be very tiny.  If I was concerned about the performance here, I'd try to combine the SELECT with the UPDATE here and do this in one statement on the server.